# Find out the derivative of $x^2 cos (\frac{1}x)$ at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity, solution-verification

> **QUESTION:** Consider the following function $$\begin{cases} x^2 \cos (\frac{1}x) \text{ }, \text{ } x \neq 0 \\ a\text{ } , \text{ } x=0 \end{cases}$$
> Then find -

> i)  the value of $a$ for which the above function is continuous.

> ii) $f'(0)$.

> iii) $ \lim _{ x \to 0 } f'(x)$

---

**MY ANSWER:** The first one is quite trivial. We know that $\cos \theta$ is an oscillating function between $[-1,1]$ and therefore, the limiting value at $x=0$ is zero.

$\because 0\times \cos ( \text{anything} ) = 0$.

$\therefore$ If the function has to be continuous at $x=0$, then $a=0$.

Now, the next two questions are a bit confusing.. Here's what I have done..

$$y=f(x)=x^2\cos(\frac{1}x)$$ $$\implies \frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x)=x^2 \big(-\sin( \frac{1}x ) \big) \big(- \frac{1}{x^2} \big) + \cos( \frac{1}x ) 2x$$ $$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x) = 2x\cos(\frac{1}x) + \sin(\frac{1}x)$$ Well and good, so to find $f'(0)$ we just plug in $x=0$ in the above equation to get $$f'(0)=0+ \text{magic :P}$$
Quite clearly, $f'(0)$ is not defined because $\sin(\frac{1}0)$ can take any possible value in $[-1,1]$ and hence, is not well defined..

Now, what is probably the difference between question (ii) and (iii) ?
They both seem to be not defined..

We know that $\sin(\frac{1}0)$ is not defined. So it is, when $x \to 0$, isn't it?

I am stuck with concepts here.. Can you please help me out?

Thank You so much for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition:

$$f'(0)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(h)-f(0)}h$$

$$\lim_{x\to0} f'(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h\right)$$

see the subtle difference?

Also you need Sandwich/Squeeze to formally evaluate $a$ in (i).